# Store text file content line by line into array

Tags: java, arrays

all,I'm now facing the problem of no idea on storing the content in text file into the array.
The situation is like, text file content:

```
abc1
xyz2
rxy3
```

I wish to store them into array line by line, is that possible? What I expect is like this:

```
arr[0] = abc1
arr[1] = xyz2
arr[2] = rxy3
```

I've try something like this, but seem like not work for me. If anyone can help me, really thanks a lot.

The code is:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/of/text"));
        String str;

        while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
            String[] arr = str.split(" ");
            for(int i=0 ; i<str.length() ; i++){
                arr[i] = in.readLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: *"but seem like not work for me"*  What error or exception resulted?  Copy/paste it to the forum as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16100175/edit).

Comment: If you want the entire line in each array element, why are you splitting it?

Comment: i thought the split(" ") can help me differentiate the next line? so that it can become lien 1,2,3..

Comment: @salemkhoo `in.readLine()` has already read the line for you.

Comment: Thanks NilsH, i learned it, :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would recommend using an `ArrayList`, which handles dynamic sizing, whereas an array will require a defined size up front, which you may not know.  You can always turn the list back into an array.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/of/text"));
String str;

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
    list.add(str);
}

String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, Kevin, you really help me a lots, thanks!

Comment: hi Kevin, thanks for your answer, my doubt is how I can print the stringArr when I tried to print the stringArr i am getting some output like [Ljava.lang.String;@17bd8e. Can anyone suggest me what is the correct way to print the contents of stringArr.

Comment: Use Arrays.toString(stringArr) to print the content of array.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest solution:

```
List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path/of/text"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String[] a = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Note that java.nio.file.Files is since 1.7

Answer (score 3):

This should work because it uses List as you don't know how many lines will be there in the file and also they may change later.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/of/text"));
String str=null;
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
    lines.add(str);
}
String[] linesArray = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
```

Comment: hi Guys, thanks for the answer, my doubt is how I can print the linesArray when I tried to print the linesArray i am getting some output like [Ljava.lang.String;@d8dc5a. Can anyone suggest me what is the correct way to print the contents of linesArray.

Answer (score 3):

## JAVA 8 :

```
Files.lines(new File("/home/abdennour/path/to/file.txt").toPath()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this for your case:-

```
int i = 0;
while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
    arr[i] = str;
    i++;
}
```

But note that the `arr` should be declared properly, according to the number of entries in your file.

**Suggestion:-** Use a `List` instead(Look at **@Kevin Bowersox** post for that)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

```
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(new FileInputStream("path/of/text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String[] arr = new String[3];// if size is fixed otherwise use ArrayList.
int i=0;
while((str = in.readLine()) != null)          
    arr[i++] = str;

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `str = in.readLine()) != null` you read one line into `str` variable and if it's not null execute the `while` block. You do not need to read the line one more time in `arr[i] = in.readLine();`. Also use lists instead of arrays when you do not know the exact size of the input file (number of lines).

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/of/text"));
String str;

List<String> output = new LinkedList<String>();

while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
    output.add(str);
}

String[] arr = output.toArray(new String[output.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this full code for your problem. 
For more details you can check it on [appucoder.com](http://www.appucoder.com)

```
class FileDemoTwo{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        FileDemoTwo ob = new FileDemoTwo();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("read.txt"));
        String str;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((str =in.readLine()) != null ){
            list.add(str);
        }
        String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(" "+Arrays.toString(stringArr)); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest use Apache IOUtils.readLines for this. See link below.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. This works very fast!

```
public String[] loadFileToArray(String fileName) throws IOException {
    String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
    return Arrays.stream(s.split("\n")).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String a =  "John\n" +
            "Michael Kai\n" +
            "Susan Elrond";
    String[] b = a.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```